# Proxy Error in nova docker installation

Tags: python, docker, pip, centos7, openstack-nova

When I install [`nova-docker`](https://github.com/stackforge/nova-docker) from `github` repositories it runs `setup.py`; from that script some packages are downloaded and installed but after that it raises a `ProxyError` during the installation.

```
Downloading unittest2-1.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (95kB): 95kB downloaded
Downloading/unpacking linecache2 (from traceback2->testtools>=0.9.22->fixtures>=0.3.14->oslo.concurrency>=0.1.0)
Cleaning up...

Exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 298, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1202, in prepare_files
    do_download,

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1380, in unpack_url
    self.session,

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 546, in unpack_http_url
    resp = session.get(target_url, stream=True)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 237, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 456, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 559, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 378, in send
    raise ProxyError(e)

ProxyError: ('Cannot connect to proxy.', gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known'))

Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
error: /bin/python -m pip.__init__ install   'pbr>=0.5.21,<1.0' 'Babel>=1.3' 'six>=1.7.0' 'oslo.serialization>=1.0.0               # Apache-2.0' 'oslo.utils>=1.0.0                       # Apache-2.0' 'oslo.config>=1.4.0  # Apache-2.0' 'oslo.concurrency>=0.1.0  # Apache-2.0' 'docker-py>=0.5.1' returned 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put proxy setting in bash file of centos.

export http_proxy="http://PROXY=USERNAME=HERE:PROXY=PASSWORD=HERE@URL:PORT"

export https_proxy="https://PROXY=USERNAME=HERE:PROXY=PASSWORD=HERE@URL:PORT"

export ftp_proxy="ftp://PROXY=USERNAME=HERE:PROXY=PASSWORD=HERE@URL:PORT"